# How do I input an integer on a new line

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make an input integer on a new line using python, but I get an error when I do this.

```
#inputs myMath as an integer
print = ("Give me a number and I will double it for you.")
myMath = int(input + "\n")

#Multiplies myMath(the variable) times 2
result = eval("2 * myMath")
```

The error says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'"
I am using python 3.5.1.

Comment: Please don't use `eval` with untrusted input. If you really need to accept "any old Python literal", use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the input, then perform the math in "real" (non-`eval`-ed) Python. e.g. `myMath = ast.literal_eval(myMath)`, `result = 2 * myMath`. If you don't need "any old Python literal", then stick to actual constructors that parse strings, e.g. `int`, `float`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
yourVal = int(input("Double a number:\n"))
result = yourVal*2
print(result)
```